# Weird behaviour with NSString - possible memory issue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsstring

I'm stepping through my code and noticed a strange behaviour with a local NSString variable.

At random calls to method which contains the local NSString variable the data seems to go corrupt or something.

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *sourceValue = [NSString string];
    NSString *targetValue = [NSString string];

    [element attributeForName:item.target].stringValue = item.source;

    sourceValue = item.source;
    targetValue = [element attributeForName:item.target].stringValue;

    if ([item.target isEqualToString:@"hidden"])
        dynamicControl.isHidden = [sourceValue boolValue];

    if (![targetValue isEqualToString:sourceValue])
        valid = NO;
```

Please see image below of the "corrupted" data which the variable targetValue holds - at random calls to my method:

[image]

It this perhaps  memory that gets changed underneath me or something?

NOTE: I'm using ARC.

Your help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: It looks like a character set encoding issue.

Comment: I wonder if this is a problem with the running code or with the debugger's ability to display the correct information.  If you print information about the string when you see that (its length, for example) does it match the "corrupt" version or what you expect?

Comment: There have been similar questions recently, which I just don't find. I had the same and believe it is a debugger error. But I had it in cases where the displayed content of the NSString started off with the full correct value (as expected) and was just continued with this type of randomic text. If I got the same output as you got then I would assume that my NSString is not nil but empty. @""

Comment: Thanks to everybody that replied. I guess all the comments was in a way correct and I concluded that the actual string in question here had funny character in it. So I guess its the debugger that's not able to encode it correctly.